# Minimizing stress and deflection (separately) using higher-order theory for static analyses of functionally graded cantilever beams

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, solidmechanics

I wanted to generate an FGM beam's optimized volume fraction, minimizing stress and deflection separately. I wanted to use the following article as a reference for the related equations.

DOI 10.1007/s00419-010-0435-6
The FGM cantilever beam, discretized into 16 elements (L = 1.2 m, h = 0.012 m, b = 0.1 m), is subjected to a concentrated force P at the free end (P = 1,000 N). The beam is composed of alumina (Al2O3) (Ea =151 GPa) and steel (Eb = 75.5 GPa).Poisson ratio is constant (νa = νb = 0.3).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are the pictures from the papers I was following. I wanted to optimize it using the differential evolution algorithm. I have attempted the code several times but am not getting anywhere. Need guidance. Thank You.

Comment: Please add the Mathematica code you've tried, even if it's incomplete. A question with pictures, but without code, may be off-topic. Please see this help page for advice on how to ask a good question: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).